# Replace string after 3 different strings and between double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need your help again with a regex.

I have this string:

> some string
>
> text1
>
> name="yyy", path="C:/asdf/qwer.jpg" type="jjj"
>
> text2
>
> name="3yu", path="C:/asdf/12t2.mov" type="uuu"

And I have this regex by far:

```
/\b(string\b(.|\n)*?)\btext1\b/
```

Now, I need to replace the path of `text1` so the output will be:

> some string
>
> text1
>
> name="yyy", path="**D:/here/is/my/another/path.png**" type="jjj"
>
> text2
>
> name="3yu", path="C:/asdf/12t2.mov" type="uuu"

I know that I need to use this also (lmk if I wrong, also what is better to use?):

```
/".*?"/
```

or:

```
/"[^"]*"/
```

But how do I tell it to replace like I need?

Comment: What is the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace that string this way:

```js
var re = /(string[\s\S]*?text1[\s\S]*?\bpath=")[^"]+/; 
var str = 'some string\n\ntext1\n\nname="yyy", path="C:/asdf/qwer.jpg" type="jjj"\n\ntext2\n\nname="3yu", path="C:/asdf/12t2.mov" type="uuu"';
var subst = '$1D:/here/is/my/another/path.png'; 
document.write(str.replace(re, subst).replace(/\n/g,"<br/>"));
```

The regex is

```
/(string[\s\S]*?text1[\s\S]*?\bpath=")[^"]+/
```

**EXPLANATION:**

- `(string[\s\S]*?text1[\s\S]*?\bpath=")` - a capturing group that will capture the text into group 1 that we'll refer to later usign a `$1` backreference in the replacement string. It matches:

  - `string` - literal `string`
  - `[\s\S]*?` - any 0 or more characters, as few as possible
  - `text1` - `text1` literally
  - `[\s\S]*?` - any 0 or more characters, as few as possible
  - `\bpath="` - matches `path="` literally with a non-word character (e.g. space) before `path` (you may remove it if it is part of a longer word)
- `[^"]+` - 1 or more characters other than `"`.

Comment: It works, but sometimes I need it to replace the path after the regex match 'string' then 'text2' and then the path..

Comment: I updated the code and added an explanation. Note that since in JavaScript there is no `s` modifier that makes dot match newline, we have to use `[\s\S]` or `[^]`.

Comment: @Ziki if you have a case where there is no `path` in `text1` then this will replace `path` of `text1`

Answer (score 1):

```
(\bstring\b[\s\S]*?\btext1\b(?:(?!\btext\d+\b)[\s\S])*path=")[^"]*
```

You can use this.Replace by `$1mypath`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/3

```
var re = /(\bstring\b[\s\S]*?\btext1\b(?:(?!\btext\d+\b)[\s\S])*path=")[^"]*/g; 
var str = 'some string\n\n    text1\n\n    name="yyy", path="C:/asdf/qwer.jpg" type="jjj"\n\n    text2\n\n    name="3yu", path="C:/asdf/12t2.mov" type="uuu"\n';
var subst = ' $1mypath'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```